# Splitting one Attribute into several new Tables/Attributes

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I hope you can help me with a structural SQL problem. Code would be great but I mainly want to get the concept if possible.

I want to create a database that tracks (besides other things) Projects and who is working on them. The planning will be done yearly but one project can span several years.

So for example:
Project ABC is created and spans from 1.1.2019 to 1.1.2021. So two years. Each year has seperate costs, hours worked on etc. And this information needs to be stored.

Sounds simple, just several colums like "cost year 1", "cost year 2" but this doesnt seems optimal.

Example one project spans 10 years, one is done within a year. Both would have 10 colums "cost year X". 9 of which would be empty for the shorter project... You see the issue...

Is there a good way to integrate something like that?

It also is kind of an issue in the doing:
I want to just create a new project with a specific Timeframe. Additional Rows (Project X year 1, Project X year 2...) should be created automatically(?) If this is an solution at all maybe a different approach is better all together.

Comment: Seems simple to me: (year, cost). The key is to store costs separate from other project details (i.e., a separate table)

Comment: So one table projects and one table project details (with cost, time spent ...etc)
Sounds simple enough. Actually so simple I fell kinda stupid now ^^